# To display an image in RCP - View, what do i do?

Tags: java, image, eclipse-plugin, swt, rcp

I have got a code snippet to display image in SWT Application which is

```
 Image image = new Image(display, "c:\\temp\\swt.png");
```

To display the same in View of RCP application?
What do i do? How do i display the image from an Absolute Path?

```
    View{

        createPartControl(){
Image image = new Image(display, "c:\\temp\\swt.png");

        }
    }
```

We cant use "display" in the createPartControl method.

Comment: Try `Display.getCurrent()` or `Display.getDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

The display is also available in a view. There are several ways to get it, one of which is:

```
Display display = Display.getDefault();

new Image(display, ....);
```

Your view is also given a `Composite` so you can also do:

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent)
{
  .... other code ...

  Display display = parent.getDisplay();

  new Image(display, ....);
```

The one thing you must **not** do is try to create a new `Display` object.